# How to stop a BGSAVE in redis?

Tags: redis, backup, persistence, database-backups

I want to stop bgsave (if exists) before copy dump.rdb file for backup.

My problem is sometimes during cp the dump.rdb file an ongoing bgsave gets completed and dump.rdb file gets updated

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there's no way to stop it.

However, in order to solve your problem, you can use `mv dump.rdb back.rdb` to automatically move the dump file before copying.